# Can't start JIRA by source

Tags: java, linux, bash, process, jira

OS: CentOS

Installed JIRA by official guide:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/installing-jira-applications-on-linux-from-archive-file-938846844.html

When start JIRA, got error:

```
[jira@node1 bin]$ ./start-jira.sh

To run JIRA in the foreground, start the server with start-jira.sh -fg
executing as current user

                  `sMMMMMMMMMMMMMM+
                     MMMMMMMMMMMMMM
                     :sdMMMMMMMMMMM
                             MMMMMM
          `sMMMMMMMMMMMMMM+  MMMMMM
             MMMMMMMMMMMMMM  +MMMMM
              :sMMMMMMMMMMM   MMMMM
                     MMMMMM    `UOJ
   `sMMMMMMMMMMMMM+  MMMMMM
     MMMMMMMMMMMMMM  +MMMMM
      :sdMMMMMMMMMM   MMMMM
             MMMMMM    `UOJ
             MMMMMM
             +MMMMM
              MMMMM
               `UOJ

      Atlassian Jira
      Version : 8.5.1


If you encounter issues starting or stopping JIRA, please see the Troubleshooting guide at https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/jadm-docs-085/Troubleshooting+installation

Using JIRA_HOME:       /home/jira/jirasoftware-home

Server startup logs are located in /home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone/logs/catalina.out
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone/work/catalina.pid
/home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone/bin/check-java.sh: line 31: [: -ne: unary operator expected
/home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone/bin/set-gc-params.sh: line 5: [: -ge: unary operator expected
Existing PID file found during start.
Unable to read PID file. Start aborted.
```

Check JAVA_HOME:

```
[jira@node1 bin]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

Check PID:

```
[jira@node1 bin]$ ps aux | grep jira
root      8185  0.0  0.4 241148  4552 pts/0    S    06:47   0:00 sudo su - jira
root      8186  0.0  0.2 191748  2300 pts/0    S    06:47   0:00 su - jira
jira      8187  0.0  0.2 116096  2812 pts/0    S    06:47   0:00 -bash
jira      8299  0.0  0.1 155364  1876 pts/0    R+   07:04   0:00 ps aux
jira      8300  0.0  0.0 112712   960 pts/0    R+   07:04   0:00 grep --color=auto jira
```

No PID exists in the `jira` user process. Why aborted?

Comment: did you try the advice of `start-jira.sh -fg` which it suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use script to stop the jira and then start it again. As you can see in the log you have already PID file:

```
Existing PID file found during start.
```

Or you can remove the PID file by hand and try to start again

Comment: You are right. This PID was created by root user: `/home/jira/jirasoftware/atlassian-jira-software-8.5.1-standalone/work/catalina.pid`. Delete it works well.